# Appending files to a StringIO Tar archive one at a time

Tags: ruby, tar, stringio

I am writing code that utilizes the `StringIO` object and `rubygems/package` which includes `TarWriter` and `TarReader`.

My end goal is to be able to call a method `add_file` to add/append a file to the archive and then call a method `read_all_files` to read back the file names and contents of the added files.

My two methods currently stand as:

```
require "rubygems/package"

def add_file(io)
  Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(io) do |tar|
    puts "What is the name of the file you wish to add?"
    print "> "
    filename = gets.chomp
    puts

    tar.add_file(filename, 0755) do |file|
      puts "Enter the file contents"
      print "> "
      contents = gets.chomp

      file.write contents
    end
  end
end

def read_all_files(io)
  Gem::Package::TarReader.new(io) do |tar|
    tar.each do |tarfile|
      puts "File Name> #{tarfile.full_name}"
      puts tarfile.read
    end
  end
end

#usage:

io = StringIO.new

add_file(io)
add_file(io)
add_file(io)
io.rewind
read_all_files(io)
```

Output:

```
What is the name of the file you wish to add?
> test1

Enter the file contents
> this is the first test
What is the name of the file you wish to add?
> test2

Enter the file contents
> this is the second test
What is the name of the file you wish to add?
> test3

Enter the file contents
> this is the third test
File Name> test1
this is the first test
```

The problem that is currently happening is that for one reason or another `read_all_files` is only reading a single file although I should be iterating all three files.

I have tried various ideas such as rewinding the file after each `add_file` call, but this overwrites the tar file each time. I have also tried to seek to the end of the io object and add the files but this also does not function correctly.

I initially thought that `TarWriter` would read the header and automatically append new files to the tar archive in the correct position, but it seems that this is not the case.

This seems as if I will need to read all files from the `StringIO` tar archive to variables and then re-add all the files each time a new file is added. Is this proper behavior? Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are creating a new TarWriter each time you call add_file. You need to preserve the TarWriter object between calls to add_file. e.g.

```
require "rubygems/package"

def add_file(io, tar=nil)

  tar = Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(io) if tar.nil?

  puts "What is the name of the file you wish to add?"
  print "> "
  filename = gets.chomp
  puts

  tar.add_file(filename, 0755) do |file|
    puts "Enter the file contents"
    print "> "
    contents = gets.chomp

    file.write contents
  end

  tar
end

def read_all_files(io)
  Gem::Package::TarReader.new(io) do |tar|
    puts 'TarReader created'
    tar.each do |tarfile|
      puts "File Name> #{tarfile.full_name}"
      puts tarfile.read
    end
  end
end

io = StringIO.new

tar1 = add_file(io)
tar1 = add_file(io, tar1)
tar1 = add_file(io, tar1)
io.rewind
read_all_files(io)
```

The output from this:

```
   C:\Users\Administrator\test>ruby tarwriter.rb
   What is the name of the file you wish to add?
   > x.txt
   Enter the file contents
   > xxx
   What is the name of the file you wish to add?
   > z.txt
   Enter the file contents
   > zzz
   What is the name of the file you wish to add?
   > y.txt
   Enter the file contents
   > yyy
   TarReader created
   File Name> x.txt
   xxx
   File Name> z.txt
   zzz
   File Name> y.txt
   yyy
```